# How to send an html page as an attachment with email in Perl

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi, perl-module

I recently started programming I know how to send a mail in perl, but I am generating a Scrollable tables in HTML page and I need to send it as an attachment in Perl and I have no idea about it. Could anyone help me?
**Edit:**
This question is different then [How can I send an HTML email with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623651/how-can-i-send-an-html-email-with-perl), I am asking for send html page as an attachment rather then sending a html Email

Comment: you need to create a multi-part message refer to this module http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm and look at this section : Create a multipart message (i.e., one with attachments) and send it SMTP

Comment: @smith FYI, the docs for MIME::Lite say, "**WAIT!** MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else."

Comment: MIME::Lite was my goto module for sending email. I'm not sure I'm ready to let go :-)

Comment: What module do you currently use to send your emails?

Comment: I am using this module "use MIME::Lite;" for mails

Comment: @jkeuhlen This is not a duplicate Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you are already using [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.029/lib/MIME/Lite.pm), they explicitly say how to do this in their documentation:

```
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
     To      =>'you@yourhost.com',
     Subject =>'HTML with in-line images!',
     Type    =>'multipart/related'
);
$msg->attach(
    Type => 'text/html',
    Data => qq{
        <body>
            Here's <i>my</i> image:
            <img src="cid:myimage.gif">
        </body>
    },
);
$msg->attach(
    Type => 'image/gif',
    Id   => 'myimage.gif',
    Path => '/path/to/somefile.gif',
);
$msg->send();
```

However, as has been pointed out in the comments and on their documentation page. You should really use an alternative. [Mail::Sendmail](http://search.cpan.org/~mivkovic/Mail-Sendmail/Sendmail.pm) works fine and tells you how to do this in their [documentation](http://alma.ch/perl/Mail-Sendmail-FAQ.html#attachments)