# How can I force outlook to interpret and display an html file correctly

Tags: outlook

From linux, I send this file to an outlook account...

```
<html>
<h2>HELLO</h2>
</html>
```

It appears just as you see, plain text.
How can I get this to display on Outlook as it appears when I run it through firefox on liunux ?

In linux, I sent it as plain test using a system call in a perl script....

```
mail -s 'the title' 'recipient' < the_file.html.
```

'which mail' eventually ends up being mailx

The thinking is that outlook would recognize the "html" (between the < and > which won't display here) as line 1 and do the right thing.

Comment: please let us know how you sent that mail.

most smtp client implementations provide a functionality to set a flag saying an email is an html-mail or just plain text.

Comment: I sent it as plain test using a system call in a perl script....   mail -s 'the title' 'recipient' < the_file.html.   'which mail' eventually ends up being mailx

Comment: so you do not want to send a mail, you want to open a html file with a mail client?

Comment: I definitely want to send email from the perl script.  The info is in a file.  I picked html because some of the text needs to be colored.  But I'm not married to html.  It there's some other way I can mail a flat file to Outlook and have it show certain words as red/green/blue (as I choose), that would  be great.

Comment: The filename extension is ".html", thinking/hoping Outlook would recognize that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct ContentType in the header. 
e.g.:
 `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Here is an old example in Perl that might help you:
[How can I send an HTML email with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623651/how-can-i-send-an-html-email-with-perl)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, we also had "mutt" installed and I was able to use that.
E.g.

```
my $cmd = "mutt -e 'set content_type=text/html' -s '${title}' '${to_list}' < ${email_file}"
my $stat = system($cmd);
```